# Create PDF using Rhtml and iterate over data frame

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I have a data frame that has demographic information split into 16 groups. I basically need to iterate over these groups and create a PDF page for each group. I've tried using Rhtml but so far I can only get one page to generate. Is there a way to use templates or something?

Comment: You might pre-process an `Rmd` file, create multiple `Rmd` file programmatically to be joined,and I love to promote this related feature of [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need PDF output, why don't you directly compile `.Rnw` to `.pdf`?

Here an example using the `iris` dataset. It prints the first few rows of each species on a new page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<results = "asis", echo = FALSE>>=
library(xtable)

newpage <- ""

invisible(lapply(unique(iris$Species), FUN = function(x) {

  cat(newpage)
  cat(sprintf("\\section{%s}", x))
  current <- head(subset(x = iris, subset = Species == x))
  print(xtable(current))
  newpage <<- "\\clearpage"
}))
@

\end{document}
```

I additionally used `xtable` to easily get a nicely formatted table. The output looks like this:[image]